# How to align image to right on FreeMarker

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I'm trying to align the last image on the right side of the page in order to make it looks like simmetric

The code I'm using on FTL is the following but it is always next to the middle section:

```
            <table class="header">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle">
                        <img src="${logo1}" style="float: left; margin: 7px; width: 120px; height: 67.5px" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" style=" margin-left: 50px;">
                        <span class="infos" style="font-size:17pt"><b>${info}</b></span><br/>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="right">
                        <img src="${lastLogo}" style="float: right; margin: 7px; width: 120px; height: 67.5px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

[image: Overview example]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what the hell are you using inline style for? Isn't it better to use classes?
Give a graphic example of how it should look like in the end.

Comment: @Grzegorz I added an example. I'm a newbie so I am ok using any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your table take up 100% width, it will do as you desire.

```html
<table class="header" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
      <img src="${logo1}" style="float: left; margin: 7px; width: 120px; height: 67.5px" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style=" margin-left: 50px;">
      <span class="infos" style="font-size:17pt"><b>${info}</b></span><br/>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle">
      <img src="${lastLogo}" style="float: right; margin: 7px; width: 120px; height: 67.5px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example below, but don't use styly inline that way.
We currently use tables for tabular data, otherwise we create everything on div.

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="header">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/120x60/ff0000/fff" style="width: 120px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="infos" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0 20px; font-size:17px; max-width: 120px;">
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</b>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/120x60/4efc03/000" style="width: 120px;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Better solution**

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header img {
  width: 120px;
}

.infos {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/120x60/ff0000/fff"></div>
  <div class="infos">
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</b>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/120x60/4efc03/000"></div>
</div>
```